# if-else undefined variable compile error

Tags: compiler-construction, go

```
if someCondition() {
    something := getSomething()
} else {
    something := getSomethingElse()
} 

print(something)
```

in this code example, compiler gives an `undefined: something` error. Since this is an if else statement `something` variable  will be defined in the runtime, but compiler fails detect this.

How can I avoid this compile error, also will this be fixed in the next versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code fragment, you're defining two `something` variables scoped to each block of the if statement.

Instead, you want a single variable scoped outside of the if statement:

```
var something sometype
if someCondition() {
    something = getSomething()
} else {
    something = getSomethingElse()
} 

print(something)
```

Answer (score 1):

The two `something` variables are two different variables with different scopes. They do not exist outside the if/else block scope which is why you get an undefined error.

You need to define the variable outside the if statement with something like this:

```
var something string

if someCondition() {
    something = getSomething()
} else {
    something = getSomethingElse()
} 

print(something)
```